# is it possible to set a "watch" on an HTML element such that it hits a javascript debugger breakpoint when the HTML element changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, watch

Is it possible to set up a "listener" of some sort on an HTML element such that when this element is changed (perhaps by javascript / jQuery) the javascript debugger breaks on the line of code that changed it?

When my web page loads I see a list of "li" list item of text.  Initially the text is legible,however, at some point there is some javascript/ jquery code  that changes the list items to scrunch up together thus no longer making as easy to read.

is it possible to sort of "guard" these list items or make them read-only so that anything that tries to change them throws an exception?

Comment: Some browsers (notably Opera) are prone to giving a "FOUC" (Flash Of Unstyled Content) before the CSS kicks in, so the effect you're seeing may be caused by CSS, not Javascript. Try eliminating CSS before looking for a Javascript cause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Chrome, you can do this by inspecting an element, and then in the Elements view, right click the DOM node you want to break on and select the desired behavior from the "Break on" menu.